# Assigning multiple roles to user in DNN programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am trying to programmatically assign multiple roles to a user in DNN.

Using the following code :

```
Roles_controller.AddUserRole(0, user_id, role_id, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(10));
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearUserCache(0, user_name);
Roles_controller.ClearRoleCache(0);
```

The problem is, no matter how many roles I assign to the user, only the last role that I assigned to the user is actually assigned. The previous assignment of roles to users were ignored. No Errors where thrown..

How can I achieve this ? Is there any limitation in DNN to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a method that I wrote to add a role to a user.  It works for me to call it multiple times, even in a loop.

```
public bool AddRoleToUser(int portalid, UserInfo user, string roleName, DateTime expiry)
{
    bool rc = false;
    if (user != null)
    {
        var roleCtl = new RoleController();
        RoleInfo newRole = roleCtl.GetRoleByName(portalid, roleName);
        if (newRole != null)
        {
            roleCtl.AddUserRole(portalid, user.UserID, newRole.RoleID, DateTime.MinValue, expiry);
            // Refresh user and check if role was added
            user = UserController.GetUserById(portalid, user.UserID);
            rc = user.IsInRole(roleName);
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Maybe it was the call to refresh the user that refreshed it from the cache.